# Ansible become method

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is it possible to use two `ansible_become:` inside one task in an Ansible playbook

I don't have `Root` access on the server I'm developing for, but I have been granted `pbrun su - USER`. The USER has **no password**. From my understanding you can only one declare one `ansible_become:` inside a task.

Has anyone ever encountered this, or is there a work around??

**code**

```
- name: change user and run shell
  become: yes
  become_method: pbrun su
  become_user: USER
```

Thanks,

Frostie

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible, the documentation states that in an example:
[become directives](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#directives)

They can be set in the inventory file or as variables and are independent:

> Become vars & directives are independent, i.e. setting become_user does not set become.

Comment: Can you give a example, not sure what you mean, I have seen the documentation ie: `- name: Run a command as the apache uesr
  command: somecommand
  become: true
  become_user: apache` but in my case I don't have root access so this still doesn't work

Comment: Maybe there is a bit of a misunderstanding. The remote_user will log in, then you want to become another user? That is how it works. You dont need to run the playbook as root, as long as you can connect to the machine. Could you maybe describe it a bit more in detail?